# How are array values stored in Little Endian vs. Big Endian architecture

Tags: c, arrays, endianness

I am inquiring about how to tell when one element in an array has finished and another is beginning in an endian architecture.

I have 2 arrays where the size of `long` is 8 and the size of `char` is 1

`long x[2] = {0x012345,0xFEDC};`

`char c[12] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','0','1','2','3'};`

And I was wondering how these values would be stored in the different Endian architectures if we consider `x` starting at memory address `0x100` and `c` starting at memory address `0x200`.

I thought that the Big Endian address would be `{01,23,45,FE,DC}` where the first element of the set is at memory address `0x100`, the next is `0x101`, third is `0x102`, and so on since it stores the values based on the MSB being first. However, I'm not sure if there is supposed to be an indicator between values that represent an array in memory to show that it's a different element, like `'\0'` (null char). like `{01, 23, 45,'\0', FE, DC}`

Likewise for the Little Endian Architecture I believe it would store it as `{45,23,01,DC,FE}`, but I am not sure whether there should be some indicator to highlight the different elements in the array

Comment: You have an array of longs. A long will typically be the word size of the platform, so 4 or 8 bytes. So why would two longs total 5 bytes of memory usage, with each using only bytes with significant digits? How could a computer ever possibly access this in a sane manner?

Comment: @Sanhadrin: I don't believe "sane" is the correct way to state it. At the very worst, it could simply be integrated into a compiler. But there is no *reason* for null separating bytes or otherwise indicate the length, because the size of each element is *implicitly* stated by its type.

Comment: @Sanhadrin "long will typically be the word size of the platform" is an over generalization - many counter examples exist.

Comment: @Jongware Considering it violates the standard, results in unaligned accesses, and would require significantly more overhead for tracking associated indices, insertions, and deletions, it's not sane in any way.

Comment: @Sanhadrin: But that's because C is designed to be  'close to the metal'. If the 'metal' were any different, a 5-byte type could make sense. Over the years, data type size has increased from 2 to (what?) 10 or 12 bytes -- *in* the same standard (of which there are actually lots). If there *would be* a 5-byte type, there is still no need for a padding byte, as having it would violate yet other parts of the standard(s).

Comment: @chux It's a generalization that's suitable enough to be both accurate based on the totality of platforms and compilers in recent and modern usage, while qualifying it to ensure that the reader knows it doesn't have to be the case (though anyone who programs should know what the standard says and why fixed-width types were included) and being illustrative of the point. When there's an MSVC tag, or code shows they're including Windows headers, obviously the answer can be tailored further.

Comment: @Jongware All of that is completely irrelevant. It's the idea of mixed-size elements being accessed by an array in any sensible manner, when an array in C has a implementation and pointer equivalency requirements that make this sort of implementation a complete non-starter. These also aren't "padding bytes", they're separators. Padding bytes already exist, to ensure alignment requirements are met on many platforms. Regardless, this isn't a very constructive conversation.

Comment: @Sanhadrin Suggest most platform in 2014 are embedded ones - over 1 billion per year.  A very large number of these have native 8 and 16-bit integers.  So while 'long' is 4 bytes there, it is not the word size of the platform.  Not sure why your answer ventures into Windows/MVSC.

Comment: @chux 1 billion? ..um, ARM shipped over 10 billion chips alone for each of the past two years. They're easily the leader for embedded processors for consumer systems, and their top-selling offerings are all 32-bit. Like I said - "typical". I brought up MSVC because it's far and away the most well-known common example where a long does NOT match platform word size on 64-bit systems when compiled as a 64-bit target because of the LLP64 model. Quit being pedantic.

Comment: @Sanhadrin Good to know ARM is so successful with 32-bit. Concerning advice what a commenter should do or be, I prefer to focus on questions, comments and answer themselves and [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In little-endian, the bytes are stored in the order least significant to most signficant. Big-endian is the opposite. For instance, `short x=0x1234` would be stored as `0x34`,`0x12` in little-endian.

As  already mentioned, it only affects the order of the bytes of a variable, and not the order of bits inside each byte. Likewise, the order of the elements of a C array are unaffected by endianness. `array[1]` always starts one `sizeof(*array)` after `array[0]`.

> However, I'm not sure if there is supposed to an indicator between
>   values that represent an array in memory to show that it's a different
>   element, like a null char.

There is no such indicator.

> {01,23,45,FE,DC}
>
> {45,23,01,DC,FE}

It would actually be

`{00,00,00,00,00,01,23,45, 00,00,00,00,00,00,FE,DC}`

and

`{45,23,01,00,00,00,00,00, DC,FE,00,00,00,00,00,00}`

because `long`s take 8 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Array elements in C are *fixed size*. That means that each element takes up exactly the number of bytes required by its type. In your example, `x` consists of two elements of type `long`. If `long` is 4 bytes on your computer, then each element takes up 4 bytes—no more, no less.

Comment: In this case the size of long is 8 bytes